# Mecha anime with the main character protecting a small girl. The main character had a friend/rival with black hair. In the end they fight

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

This anime starts with the main character protecting a small girl. They're underground, hiding from the government. Out of nowhere, just in time the main character's rival/friend beats the government robots. He doesn't really like the small child yet he protects her. The government wants her, as so do pirates. This child is a very special child.

I could add that in one episode they meet this one kid who is a pirate, but he's cool. He even plays with a frog with the small child. She even calls him a frog. They steal government mecha together just to protect this small girl.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This is pretty tropey. Can you offer any more info about the girl (name, age), why she's so special, whether these are literal pirates, what the setting is (e.g. modern, futuristic, steampunk, etc) and any names you can recall (for example, did they call the mecha "mecha" or "mechsuits" or whatever)